# Fingerprint recognition in java

Tags: java, fingerprint

how to do a fingerprint recognition program in java without any fingerprint reader device, by using fingerprint image.Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a fingerprit recognition library that you are working with or are you writing your own?

Comment: This is probably not an achievable task for someone whose 'best effort' is coming here to implore people for 'da codez'.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps:

1. Buy a commercial fingerprint toolkit
2. Integrate into your application
3. ...???
4. Profit!

I don't believe there is an open-source fingerprint recognition toolkit, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Note that 'open source' is not necessarily the same as 'free'.  I suspect the OP actually wants 'free'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [biometric SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/)? I haven't used it but it looks like it might be what you want.